# Session timer in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to organize notification which will tell user, that his session will be end after some minutes. For this after page load I get total session time, and parameter which tells me when I must show notification(for example 1000secs-session time and 60-time which remains till session is end) from api. How I understand I need to organize a timer with setTimeout method. But I can't realize how to organize this mechanism acording to react philosophy. How can it be performed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your root component set a timeout and show a notification.
I dont know how you get the session time, but lets assume that the session time is just available. Then you can do something like this (using ES6):

```
const React = require('react');
const PropTypes = require('prop-types');

export class Main extends React.Component
{
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        timerid: -1,
        sessionEndsSoon: false, 
    };
    this.getSessionTimeout = this.getSessionTimeout.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount()
  {
    this.setState({ timerid: this.getSessionTimeout() });
  }

  componentWillUnmount()
  {
    clearTimeout(this.state.timerid);
  }

  getSessionTimeout()
  {
      if (this.state.timerid)
      {
          clearTimeout(this.state.timerid);
      }
      timerid = setTimeout(() =>
      {
          this.setState({sessionEndsSoon : true});
      }, this.props.sessionTimeInMs);
      return timerid;
  }

  render()
  {
    if(this.state.sessionEndsSoon)
    {
      return (<p>Session ends soon</p>);
    }
    return (<p>session active</p>);
   }
}
Main.propTypes = {
  sessionTimeInMs: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};

Main.defaultProps =
{
   sessionTimeInMs: 1000000,
};
```

Futhermore you can get the session time from the backend via ajax and update the timeout accordingly.

Comment: I don't quite understood idea( I get time params from props(I use redux). for example this.props.parameters.session_time. could you explain your solution more detailed?

Comment: In "componentDidMount" you set a timeout. When the timeout is expired a function is called which sets the state ("sessionEndsSoon") to true.